# MySQL, CodeIgniter one row joining with multiple row with row_array active record function

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I've got three table,

**Works:**

```
CREATE TABLE `works` (
  `work_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `work_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `work_baslangic` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `work_bitis` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `work_onay` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
  `work_onay_userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `work_brief` text NOT NULL,
  `work_not` text NOT NULL,
  `work_url` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `work_employees` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`work_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

**Notifications:**

```
CREATE TABLE `notifications` (
  `notification_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `notification_userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `notification_workid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `notification_stat` enum('1','0') NOT NULL,
  `notification_tarih` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`notification_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

**Users**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip_address` varbinary(16) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `activation_code` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `forgotten_password_code` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `forgotten_password_time` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `remember_code` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `last_login` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

Scenario: When people create new work, form values inserted the works table AND notifications table. Notifications table save the who is do the jobs. It can be more than one people. I save userid and join users tables for finding who.

In the controller:

```
$data["works"]  =   $this->db->select("users.first_name, works.work_employees, works.work_name, works.work_baslangic, works.work_bitis, works.work_onay, works.work_onay_userid")->from("works")->join("users", "users.id = works.work_onay_userid", "LEFT")->get()->result_array();
```

In the view:

```
foreach($works as $row):
```

**At this line I write another sql to finding notification users. But I don't want to write another sql to view, I want to complete all of them on the controller(or model). How can I do this?**

```
endforeach;
```

Comment: Did you look at your question before posting? Please format it so that it's in an understandable state.

Comment: is this okey now? thank you @JamWaffles

Answer (score 0):

In the controller you place the following code

```
// set to null so you can check against null value in view
$notifications = null;
foreach($works as $row)
    {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `notifications` WHERE `notification_userid` = '{$row->works.work_onay_userid}'");// adapt query to your liking
    foreach($query->result() as $res)
            {
            $notifications[] = $res;
            }
    }
$data['notifications'] = $notifications;
```

This way you've done the queries already in the controller and you get the result objects in the view